# Player class needs to inherit list of cards from Deck class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I am working on a deck of cards python script that I intend to use to create basic card games. I have read up on inheritance within python and my Player class does inherit my Deck class. My problem is that my code does not follow PEP8. I also would not like the Player class to inherit the entire Deck class, rather just the card_list.

```
import random

class Card():

    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def show_card(self):
        print(str(self.value) + " of " + str(self.suit))

class Deck():

    card_list = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.construct_deck()
        self._playing_pile = []
        self._discard_pile = []

    def construct_deck(self):
        for s in ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']:
            for v in ['Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']:
                self.card_list.append(Card(v, s))

    def show_deck(self):
        for card in self.card_list:
            card.show_card()

    def show_playing_pile(self):
        for card in self._playing_pile:
            card.show_card()

    def show_discard_pile(self):
        for card in self._discard_pile:
            card.show_card()

    def shuffle_deck(self):
        self.shuffled_cards = random.shuffle(self.card_list)

    def draw_card_from_deck(self):
        self._draw_from_deck = self.card_list.pop()
        return self._draw_from_deck

    def return_card_to_deck(self):
        self._return_to_deck = self.card_list.append(self._draw_from_deck)
        return self._return_to_deck

    def put_card_in_playing_pile(self):
        self._put_in_playing_pile = self._playing_pile.append(self._draw_from_deck)
        return self._put_in_playing_pile

    def put_card_in_discard_pile(self):
        self._put_in_discard_pile = self._discard_pile.append(self._draw_from_deck)
        return self._put_in_discard_pile

class Player(Deck):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self._players_hand = []

    def player_draws_card_from_deck(self, deck):
        self._players_hand.append(deck.draw_card_from_deck())

    def player_returns_card_from_hand_to_deck(self, deck):
        self.card_list.append(self._players_hand.pop())

    def player_returns_card_from_playing_pile_to_deck(self, deck):
        self.card_list.append(self._playing_pile.pop())

    def player_returns_card_from_discard_pile_to_deck(self, deck):
        self.card_list.append(self._discard_pile.pop())

    def show_players_hand(self):
        for card in self._players_hand:
            card.show_card()
```

Any help or documents that I could read up on would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why would your `Player` class inherit `Deck`? This doesn't make much conceptual sense, `Player` isn't a type of `Deck`, you may mean Player has a Deck, which just means that you would pass the `Deck` to `Player`, e.g. in `__init__()` or some other method, which you seem to already be doing.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. Right now in `Player(Deck):` is it saying that Player has a Deck. I do mean the latter.

Comment: `Player(Deck)` would generally be interpreted as `Player` is a `Deck`.

Comment: That's unfortunate, thanks for the help though. I do appreciate it.

Comment: It's not that it's "generally interpreted" as "Player is a Deck."  It literally means that every Player object is also a Deck object. It's not the right thing to do in this case.  Also, you are passing deck objects into all of the methods, so why does the Player class need a relationship to Deck at all?

Comment: I want Player to be able to append a card that they have drawn from the deck back onto the original card_list. With my knowledge of the language I thought it made sense to create a relationship between them so that I could use card_list.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder is there anyway to do this without inheriting the Deck Class?

Comment: May be a more appropriate question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I've made a post there as well

Comment: Don't use inheritance here.